# How to know if the data can be classified in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification

In classification problem, we can adjust soft margin to make things easier. However, in some cases, especially in real-world data collections, the classification problem can be extremely hard because of the noise introduced. In 2D space, the following graph can be obtained:

[image]

We can easily conclude that these two classes of data can not be classified. However, usually the features of data can be huge, which can not be plot in 2D or 3D space. I also tried TSNE to visualize the classified data. But since TSNE uses KL to train, while SVM uses loss function, I can not get anything from the following picture.
[image]

where the green ones are true positive, blue ones are false negative, yellow ones are false positive, black ones are true negative.

So my question is: is there a scientific method that can be used to analyse whether a problem can be classified or not?

Comment: I wanted to make sure that you know about Cross Validated, which is another site in the stackexchange network dedicated to Statistics, Machine Learning etc https://stats.stackexchange.com ...I would consider posting your question there as well.

Comment: @DavidTansey I know CV can be used to evaluate the model. But still we can not know whether the problem can be classified or not. I'm going to post it there.